# Help with setting up transfer function correct format

Tags: transfer-function, scipy

I have a transfer function as:

H(s) = R / (sRC + 1)

V is the output and I is the input so we can write:

V(s) = I(s)*H(s)

Now the thing is that, I want to obtain I(t) for the given V(t). So I write:

I(s) = V(s)*1/H(s)

So in this case my new transfer function is 1/H(s) to obtain I(t) from V(t):

1/H(s) = (sRC + 1) / R

I use scipy lti as:

```
from scipy import signal

sys = signal.lti([R*C, 1], [0, R]) 
t_in, input_current, x = signal.lsim(sys, V_out, time)
```

But I get the following error:

> ValueError: Improper transfer function. `num` is longer than `den`.

Why using 1/H(s) causes this error?

Something wrong about denominator and nominator of (sRC + 1) / R ?

How to remedy this?

Comment: Yeap, you're asking the system to deal with something it's not built to handle ;)
What is your circuit?  My interpretation is RC divider, and you are asking for the reverse xfer Vin/Vout function.  In realistic situations (say a square wave) then you would be differentiating the input and trying to reconstruct the input, that requires integration with unknown boundaries.   So you can only obtain/use the first derivative of the output to reconstruct the input.  Ask for the current through the capacitor, and you get an answer. I can post a more coherent answer if needed.